# JQuery Datatable broken css on slideDown

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

My problem is that the initial div should hide onclick then show another datatable but the css is broken after slideDown.

Initial DataTable

```
<div id="data_table">
      <table id="table_id" class="table" style="width: 100%;">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Section Name</th>
            <th>Subject Name</th>
            <th>Level</th>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>School Year</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <?php foreach ($class_list as $class) { ?>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="class_list_view"  data-id="<?= $class->section_id ?>" >
                 <?= $class->section_name ?>
              </a>
            </td>
            <td><?= $class->subject_name ?></td>
            <td><?= $class->level ?></td>
            <td><?= $class->year ?></td>
            <td><?= $class->schoolyear ?></td> 
          </tr>
          <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

onclick on that `a href`... it will show this and hide the other one

```
<div id="classlist" style="display: none;">
    <table id="table_id_classlist" class="table" style="width: 100%;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Student number</th>
                <th>Full name</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

javascript

```
 $(document).ready( function () {
    $('#table_id, #table_id_classlist').DataTable({
      "aaSorting": [],
      "scrollX": true
    });
  });

 $('#class_list_view').on('click', function() {
    $('#data_table').slideUp();
    $('#classlist').slideDown();
 });
```

But then on that slideDown the output of classlist id is this

[image]

Please help me so that onclick the css (I think) isn't broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is [slideUp](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/) makes the element `display:none;`

I would recommend using css to create the transition. You will find this offers great performance benefits too.

I don't have your full code to work with but something like:

```
 $('#class_list_view').on('click', function() {
    $('#data_table').removeClass( "Active" );
    $('#classlist').addClass( "Active" );
 });
```

Then animate control behaviour with css:

```
#data_table,
#classlist {
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 0.2s;
 transition: all ease-in-out 0.2s;
}
#data_table.Active,
#classlist.Active {
  max-height: 1000px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Don't forget to apply the class `Active` to the datatable you want to be initially visible.

Comment: thanks. by the way there is an extra dot in the `#data_table,` .

Comment: @user827391012 My bad. Copy and paste is not only my hero but the cause of so many code erros :)